# How to replace function in postgress?

Tags: postgresql, rdbms, ddl

I want to change code of function.
If i use

```
CREATE FUNCTION take_proxy (VARCHAR(255)) ....
```

I get `function "take_proxy" already exists with same argument types`

Should i always firest try to delete function or is there some syntaxis for this cases?

Comment: btw, your tags are not related to your question, please fix them.

Comment: @fvu i added few. is it now more consistent? though still not sure why not related. pg - is well-known short for "postgres", "dsl" - is domain-specific language - the one, which creates tables, etc..

Comment: I think the acronym you're looking for is DDL (data definition language, the part of SQL used to define data - complemented by DML, the data manipulation language). Although [SQL could be called a DSL](http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/blog/2008/10/27/sql-is-a-dsl/), I don't think using the DSL tag here is appropriate. PG is totally unrelated as it's the tag for the Ruby extension for Postgres. You can see what all these tags mean by hovering over them, and for future reference it's quite important to have the tags right.

Comment: Please check the spelling of your title: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, [the fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createfunction.html) is the place to go:

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] FUNCTION
```

> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION will either create a new function, or replace an existing definition.